# Customs with 2 hour 35 minute layover at Fort Lauderdale

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, transit

We are flying into Ft Lauderdale FLL at 2:55 from Panama, picking up luggage and going through customs to catch 5:30 flight to San Francisco. Is this doable?

Comment: What nationality/passports do you hold?

Comment: Are the two flights in the same ticket, or did you buy them separately?

Comment: Which airline(s) are you planning to fly with? When?

Comment: Well, that is a 2:35 hour layover, not 3:00. Be sure they are on one ticket so the airline flying you to SFO has a reason to get you there.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this is 2.55pm (and not 2.55am) and it's on a single ticket, that should be fine. You can check average wait and max wait times at immigration here: https://awt.cbp.gov/ Fort Lauderdale in the afternoon should not be more than one hour.

A lot depends on your citizenship, type of document, airline status, Global Entry or equivalent, TSA PreCheck, etc.

Comment: You forgot to factor the inevitable delay and  security in. It's obviously not doable in 20222 but y'all downvoted my answer so I deleted it. _shrugs_

Comment: I've flown a fair bit in 2022 and while I had occasional snags, it's IME not nearly as bad as the press makes it out to be. Two weeks ago I did 5 legs in USA and South America. Everything was on time and there were no unusual large delays at security or immigration.